# Buildfire - Issue Loading Plugin in Previewer

Tags: javascript

For some reason, trying to load my plugin in the previewer does not work.  It begins to load with a white screen and little loading animation, but after about 2 seconds, sometimes quicker, the load seems to stop.  his is characterized by the loading animation going away, leaving only a pure white screen.

When hooking it up to the debugger and loading the plugin again I can see warnings in the console that say "Pending rest calls taking too long. Stopping spinner."  From this it seems that some type of request is being made to retrieve something on load of the plugin and it is obviously hanging.

I'm not sure how that interaction or case is taken care of internally in the previewer.  when I check the network logs, I don't see any of the files required for the plugin even being requested.  The only files that are requested are analytics files.

Moreover, I tried loading another plugin like the places the plugin.  It seems to exhibit similar behavior when it has no data.  The only difference is that it will actually load a view, and then immediately switch it out for a blank white view.  I checked the debugger network tab for that too and it shows various GET requests for templates stuck in a state of "Pending."  In this case however the warning about pending requests taking too long is not shown.

My plugin that I am trying to load has been stripped of all external calls to data sources.  This means that the only files being loaded should be the ones packaged in the zip folder when I uploaded it.  I'm not sure how to fix what seems to be a request error for the previewer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce the issues that you are seeing with the places plugin. Do you have the latest version of the SDK?

Does this issue occur for you for all plugins, or just certain plugins? What other plugins do you see it in, in addition to places and your custom plugin?

It might help if you can share the code of you custom plugin, too.

One last thing ... what App ID are you using in the plugin tester?

Comment: I am using SDK version 1.0.0.  For the ID I was originally using 9fded20a-0668-11e6-a50f-124798dea82d, but after that I had started using a newer updated version of the SDK a while back and completely got rid of the old one.  It seems the code now in the plugin tester just generates a random App ID.  I have only experienced the full issue in my custom plugin.  The same outcome occurs in the places plugin, but in a slightly different manner as I have detailed above.  My other custom plugins work just fine and were developed within the same SDK, which is why I am at a loss.

Comment: @tbergen1 Maybe I'm not following. What in particular in your custom plugin are you trying to load that's not loading? Are you having issue with both the control and the widget?

Comment: The previewer is where the issue occurs.  The widget never seems to load.  It just stays as a blank white screen, but there are no errors that are ever logged in the debugger besides the warnings that I stated in the initial explanation.

Comment: @tbergen1 The latest version of the SDK is 1.7.1. Get the the latest version from GitHub. https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk If the issue still persists, perhaps you can provide a screen shot of the error.

Comment: I have the latest version of the SDK.  I also made sure my previewer was up to date.  Everything is all square when it comes to updates.  I recently developed another plugin that is suffering from the same issue.  When I try to load that plugin (called Gateway) it seems like nothing is even loaded at all.  There are no network requests made according to the debugger.  This seems to be an issue with any new plugin that I am developing, but not with older ones...

Comment: @tbergen1 Can you provide a screen shot, or better yet a video, of what you're seeing?